# Javascript process keys in Array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

Iam using this [library](http://trackingjs.com/) to track some colors on video streamed by my webcam.

Simply the code to return tracked objects is as simple as :

```
tracker.on('track', function(event) {
        
        console.log(event.data)

                  });
```

the `event.data` is an array of objects , each object contains 5 keys `'color' , 'x' , 'y' , 'height' , 'width'` , what im trying to do is to find 2 objects which their 'Xs' has difference of 10 i.e `x1-x2=10` , or `x2-x1=10` ( lets call them adjacent objects ) , known that the `event.data` changes with real time tracking , this is not a static array.

Tried using jQuery `.grep()` , but cant figure out how to process more than item.

Comment: Depends how fast you need answers. If it's not until the video is ended, you don't need to process as fast.

Comment: Make a function that takes x as an argument and returns all of your saved events where x differs by +-10, since there may be more than one.

Comment: @ArtOfCode this is a live stream , as long as it is running , i have to process all objects.

Answer (score 0):

You'll just need to loop through the array and compare those values:

```
for var i = 0; i < event.data.length; i++ )
{
    var data1 = event.data[ i ];

    //Now we'll loop through the whole array to compare
    for ( var x = 0; x < event.data.length; x++ )
    {
        if ( Math.abs( data1.x - event.data[ x ].x ) === 10 )
        {
            return { x1: data1, x2: event.data[ x ] };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please read my question again i need to find all adjacent objects.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating another container array to contain (really?) all the arrays produced by the tracker:

```
var container = [];
tracker.on("track", function(event) {
    var newIndex = container.length;
    container[newIndex] = event.data;
    process(newIndex);
});
```

Now you have all the data saved, you can process it:

```
function process(index) {
    var adjacent = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < container.length; i++) {
        var subtract = container[index].x - container[i].x;
        if(subtract == 10 || subtract == -10)
          adjacent.push(i);
    }
    return adjacent;
}
```

So now, if `process()` returns true, you know the difference is 10. What you do with that now is up to you.

Comment: Or simply `return Math.abs(subtract) === 10;`

Comment: True. I went for this because it's easier to read at a glance.

Comment: Also, the first the event is fired, you will call `process` and try to fetch `container[-1]`...

Comment: please notice that the array is updated on every frame , and i need to find all adjacent objects , your solution will process consecutive items only .

Comment: "Adjacent"? How do you mean, @ProllyGeek?

Comment: @Johan: Fixed that bug.

Comment: No, you can't `return false` in a ternary if statement

Comment: @ArtOfCode simply i track objects on screen , to know that two objects are adjacent their Xs will have a difference of 10 or less , so i have to loop the whole array , to find what objects satisfy this condition.

Comment: `container[index - 1].x` will still throw an error since `container[index - 1]` will be `undefined` on your first call

Comment: OK, both of you (@Johan, @ProllyGeek): rewritten. Bug free and works for the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would have done it (`Array.prototype.filter` and `$.grep()` does the same thing):

```
var events = [];
tracker.on('track', function(e){
    events.push(e.data);
});

function getEventsByXDiff(x){
    return events.filter(function(e){
        return e.x - x === 10 || x - e.x === 10
    });
}

// Usage: getEventsByXDiff(someEvent.x);
```

Example with dummy event data: http://jsfiddle.net/11mvLtqp/

Comment: thanks for your answer , i dont understand your logic , but can you explain why doesnt this work ? http://jsfiddle.net/11mvLtqp/2/

Comment: @ProllyGeek It works as intended. `15` is the only match for 5 +- 10.

Comment: but i need both objects that match the process i.e 5 and 10

Comment: @ProllyGeek 5 and 10 has a difference of 5 and not 10 as you asked for in the question. Are you asking for all the matching events with x +- 10 plus the event itself?

Comment: Johan assume we have an array of [10 , 55, 30 , 5 , 12] , i need to find two elements with diff == 5 , which will output 10 & 5 they satisfy the condition .

Comment: @ProllyGeek Sorry but that makes no sense.

Comment: what makes no sense ? this is my question how to find two elements that satisfy the condition in an array , please  read my question carefully , thanks for your effort though.

Comment: @ProllyGeek Your comment "this should reuturn 30 and 5" based on "25" makes no sense. You asked for a +- 5 range, so 25 will obviously give you 20 and 30.

Comment: what i asked for is based on -+ 25 this code should turn 30 and 5 , this is simply my request , anyway guess i will have to loop the whole array.